# Reflections on a sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d, reflection, spheres

There is a sphere located in a point **s** with radius *r*. The Sphere is a perfect mirror. If i'm sitting in the point **c**, I want to cast a ray to the sphere such that I hit the point **p** after bouncing in the surface of the sphere. For this, I want to find the point **x**.

I've had some trouble formulating this problem.

How can I find **x**?

*The point **p** is always visible (in the reflection) from **c**.*

*A formulation in 2D would be  enough to begin with.*

[image]

### **NOTE**

The lines **xc** and **xp** do not have the same length. The line **sx** should be the bisector of the angle **xcp**.

I need to solve this problem analytically, can't use numeric methods to approximate the solution.

Comment: You mean angle $cxp?$

Comment: @Narasimham yes

Answer (score 6):

It seems that “[Computing a Point of Reflection on a Sphere](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/SphereReflections.pdf)” was done by David Eberly and it needs to
compute roots of a quartic polynomial.

Comment: The quartic is surprising. Physically, it seems clear that there are only two solutions -- one with external reflection (which is the one we want) and one with internal reflection. I wonder if one can show that the quartic has a quadratic factor that is never zero.

Answer (score 5):

Find the bisector of $\angle{CSP}$, then point X is the intersection of this bisector with the circle/sphere.

Note: Above simple answer only works when point C and P are symmetric to center S.

In general, the vector $\vec{SX}$ bisects $\angle{CXP}$ (not $\angle{CSP}$). So, to find point X, represented as $X=S+(rcost,rsint)$, we have to solve for the following equation:

$\frac{\overrightarrow{XC}}{|\overrightarrow{XC}|}\cdot \vec{n} = \frac{\overrightarrow{XP}}{|\overrightarrow{XP}|}\cdot \vec{n} $

, where $\vec{n}=\frac{\overrightarrow{SX}}{|\overrightarrow{SX}|}$

It is not easy to solve for point X from this equation analytically. But you can do that numerically.

Comment: It is not the bisector as you said, because the lines SC and SP are not guaranteed to have the same length.

Comment: You are right. My answer only works when point C and P are symmetric to the center S.

Comment: I revised my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Find line $l_1$ that goes through $C$ and $X$, $l_2$ through $P$ and $X$ and tangent line $l_3$ to the circle in $X$. Then write that the angle between $l_1$ and $l_3$ is equal to the angle between $l_2$ and $l_3$.

Comment: This is a straight-forward enough problem that you might want to jump to the 3-dimensional case, but good idea.

Answer (score 2):

It can be shown that the point of specular reflection on the sphere provided two focal points lying outside of it is always given by a quartic polynomial equation. In the case where all solutions are distinct, each solution corresponds respectively to an external, internal and external-internal or internal-external reflection. For the construction of an approximation of the point of interest using a geometric algorithm employing compass and ruler constructions and the error associated see https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06768

Answer (score 2):

This is well known as [Alhazen's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhazen%27s_problem).

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt at a solution for the two dimensional case. i will take the circle to be centred at the origin and have radius $r.$ i will take $c = (c_1, c_2)^T, p = (p_1, p+2)^T, x = (r\cos t, r\sin t)^T$ we will determine $t$ subject to the constraint that the line $OS$ bisects $\angle CSP$

$$ \dfrac{ c\cdot x - r}{p \cdot x - r}= \dfrac{(c-x) \cdot x}{(p-x) \cdot x} = 
\dfrac{\lvert c - x \rvert \lvert x \rvert \cos \angle CSO}{ \lvert p - x \rvert \lvert x \rvert  \cos \angle PSO} = \dfrac{\lvert c - x \rvert}{ \lvert p - x \rvert} $$

we need to solve  $$\dfrac{ c\cdot x - r}{p \cdot x - r}=
\dfrac{\lvert c - x \rvert}{ \lvert p - x \rvert} \text{ for } t. \tag 1$$

let $c.x = r|c|\cos(t+\alpha), p.x = r|p|\cos(t+\beta).$ then the previous equation (1) becomes $${\left( \dfrac{|c|\cos(t+\alpha)}{|p|\cos(t + \beta)} \right)}^2 = \dfrac{|c|^2 - 2r|c|\cos(t + \alpha)+r^2}{|p|^2 - 2r|p|\cos(t + \beta)+r^2} \tag 2$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the radius should be arbitrary, can't make it 1 for no reason.

Comment: @Xocoatzin, i fixed the radius to be $r$ not that it makes much difference. you can always set up your coordinate system and the units so that circle has radius 1.