# Find a reflection point on a sphere given source and destination of a ray

Tags: optimization, analytic-geometry

Given two 3D points, say $A = (0, 0, 0)$ and B = $(T, 0, 0)$ and a sphere $S$ of radius $r$ centered at a point $C=(a, b, c)$. The sphere does not cross the $z=0$ plain, say it is located fully below that plain, i.e. $c<-r$.

I am looking for the point $P \in S$ on the sphere such that a ray starting at the point B would arrive at the point A after bouncing off the sphere S at that point $P$. I wonder if analytical answer is possible here.

I think the problem can be written as a constrained optimization, like this:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{(T-x)^2 + y^2 + z^2} + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\rightarrow \min_{x, y, z}\\
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=r^2
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}$$
but do not understand what to do with it. Besides, I expect the reflection law to figure in here, but cannot see how to write it in.

Can anyone point me where to look for a solution or a method to find such? Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037090/reflections-on-a-sphere

Comment: This is [Alhazen's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhazen%27s_problem).

Comment: Thank you Eric, much appreciated. What do I do now to acknowledge that the solution has been pointed?

Comment: Eh...  This wasn't a solution/answer.  This was just a reference to a more complete body of literature than can reasonably be summarized into an Answer.

Comment: well, it was the answer to my question as stated (point me where to look :). So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Eric Towers in the comments, this is a known problem with a known solution. The article on Alhazen's problem in wikipedia provides a sufficient list of references.

Comment: What you wrote is not an answer.